# How to calculate rectangle tangent to sphere

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Given a rectangle $ABCD,$ how do I calculate points $A, B, C, \; \text{and}\; D\;$ if I place the rectangle tangent to a sphere, centered at a given Latitude and Longitude, and given a "Rotation" which would be degrees clockwise from "North" on the sphere?

You can assume that the sphere is a Unit Sphere centered at the Origin.
[image]

I'm trying include this in a software application, so I would appreciate solutions suitable for programming, i.e. algebra or trigonometry rather than calculus.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of matrices, you can construct your rotation matrix from simple rotation matrices. Let's have rectangle parallel to plane $yz$ (with $z$ being the axis of spherical coordinates), sides parallel to $y$ and $z$ and center on the sphere (you can derive the coordinates of the vertices yourself).

We first rotate rectangle around its central point (axis $x$) by angle $\varphi$: 
$$
\Phi=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos\varphi& -\sin\varphi\\
0 & \sin\varphi& \phantom{-}\cos\varphi
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then we rotate the rectangle by given latitude angle (around axis $y$):
$$
\Theta=\begin{pmatrix}
\phantom{-}\cos\theta& 0& \sin\theta\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
-\sin\theta& 0& \cos\varphi
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Finally, we will rotate around axis $z$ by longitude angle $\lambda$:
$$
\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\lambda& -\sin\lambda&0\\
\sin\lambda& \phantom{-}\cos\lambda & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The total rotation is the product of the matrices. Since we apply matrices to vector from left to right, the order is like this:
$$
R = \Lambda \Theta \Phi
$$

From programming point of view, you can either derive the final equation for the corners on paper and then write it in code. Or preferably, add multiplication by matrix as a function your code and apply matrix multiplication on demand. The latter case will give you more flexibility and is probably less prone to bugs.